# log4j not dsplaying the mapped urls in my controller

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

I am completely new to Spring MVC and log4j.
In a project that I referred, log4j outputs all the mapped URLs in the console at server startup.
But when I tried, it is not displaying anything about the controller methods.

I tried to change the level from INFO to DEBUG but that's too deep and not what I needed.

I wrote a single API for example purpose.
[sample api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHB5A.png)

And these are my log4j properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### direct messages to file or.log ###
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${user.home}/Documents/rough/
hermesTmp/hermes.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy 
HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{1} - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

This is my output
[doesnt show mapped url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tldXZ.png)

I need the API to be listed as shown in the project I referred
[Working code's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4ezP.png)

Any suggestions...?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The debug() method you are using on the log object in your controller will log on DEBUG level. So you can either change the method you invoke to info():

```
log.info("Everything will work this way")
```

Or you can change the level in log4j configuration to:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
```

You can check out the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html)